# Root locus, deriving the behavior at infinity

Tags: asymptotics, locus

I'm reading Control Systems Engineering of Nise, Appendice M.1, Derivation of the Behaviour of the Root Locus at Infinity (Kuo, 1987).

At one point, we have;

$$
f(s) = (1+\frac{b1-a1}{s})^{1/n}
$$

is expanded into infinite series and the first two terms are significant. We obtain;
$$
(1+\frac{b1-a1}{ns})
$$

I tried expanding into Taylor Series but couldn't derive the same expression. Missing something?

Comment: Could you please write what you got from expanding out the  yourself? The expression they'vve written is correct. If you can show what you've tried, the mistake can be pointed out

Comment: I tried to derive the same expression using the expansion below. 
$$
f(s) = f(a)+f'(a)(s-a)
$$ and thought a as (a=inf)

Comment: Hi Ethakka appam with Chai, can you please show me how to make the calculation?

Comment: That doesn't look quite right @Gundofganfa [have a look at this article I wrote](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123) on taylor series. Perhaps that will clear you doubts.

Comment: The correct eqtn should be f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a) h

Comment: if I put a+h into s, I get the same equation. But I couldn't manage to get the same expression mentioned above :/